# How can I find position of first char 's' in the string without using indexOf method

Tags: java, indexof

So what i'm trying to do is find position of first 's' of the string. So I printed out and output is 7. I want value of indexFirst be 0 since 'she' of the string contains 's'.

I kind of figured out right after I posted the question so thank you

```
public class string 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

      String str = "she is so nice";
      char replacedFirst = 's';
      int indexFirst = 0;

      for(int index = 0; index < str.length(); index++)
      {
        if(str.charAt(index) == replacedFirst)
        {
          indexFirst = index;
        }
      }
      System.out.println(indexFirst);
 }

}
```

Comment: When you found your character you have to exit the `for` loop early, no need to search further and find another position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Break` the `for loop` when you get the first occurrence of the  `char` you are searching. Your current code will currently return the last index of the char.

```
if(str.charAt(index) == replacedFirst)
{
  indexFirst = index;
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Amit said break in the for is the problem in your code.

Also `str.indexOf("s")` would do the same. You don't need for at all.

Comment: H explicitly says he does not want to use `indexOf` in the title.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can also do an enhanced `for` loop with `String.toCharArray()` to iterate on each `char`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      String str = "she is so nice";
      char replacedFirst = 'e';
      int indexFirst = 0;

      for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
          if(c == replacedFirst)
          {
              break;
          }
          indexFirst++;
      }
      System.out.println(indexFirst);
}
```

This will use your `indexFirst` and increment it each iteration, and `break` if the `char` matches.

Output for `e`:

> 2

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following snippet. If you initialize indexFirst as 0 it will always print 0 even if string contains no 's'.

```
public class string { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        String str = "she is so nice"; 
        char replacedFirst = 's'; 
        int indexFirst = -1; 
        for(int index = 0; index < str.length(); index++;  { 
            if(str.charAt(index) == replacedFirst) { 
                indexFirst = index;
                if(indexFirst != -1) {
                    break;
                }
 } } System.out.println(indexFirst); } }`
```